# how to plot time of day in y-axis in jquery Flot Charts

Tags: jquery, flot

I have time of day data to plot in y-axis.
so data set looks like

```
x,y
ex.
2015-10-01,09:05,
2015-10-02,09:15,
2015-10-03,09:20,
...
```

need to make time of day as the y-axis.
how to plot this in jquery flot?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to transform your data to a format understandable by flot. For this, convert your dates to timestamps and your time of day to an amount of hours (like 09:15 -> 9.25 hours). Then show this data in a time mode flot chart. The conversion code could look like this:

```
var originalData = [
    ['2015-10-01', '09:05'],
    ['2015-10-02', '19:15'],
    ['2015-10-03', '09:20']
];

var data = [];

for (var i = 0; i < originalData.length; i++) {
    var dataPoint = [];
    dataPoint.push((new Date(originalData[i][0])).getTime());

    var time = originalData[i][1].split(':');
    var hours = parseInt(time[0], 10);
    var minutes = parseInt(time[1], 10);

    dataPoint.push(hours + minutes / 60);
    data.push(dataPoint);
}
```

`data` now looks like this:

```
data = [
    [1443657600000, 9.08333333],
    [1443744000000, 19.25],
    [1443830400000, 9.33333333]
];
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stj0eu5q/) for a full example.